# How to store 2 values in one variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HTML

```
<div class="number" id="number7"><br>
  <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)"><span>7</span></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
function calculate(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var number = event.target.innerText; 
}
```

`calculate` only returns `7`, but I need `number7` in a javaScript variable.

Comment: are you referring to number7, the id, or the number 7 inside the span.  What do you want the calculate to do?

Comment: @NewToJS I used this function: function calculate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var number = event.target.innerText; But it only store a single number when I click the link, buttttt I want it to store as many time as I click.

Comment: Don't post code in the comments, edit your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it more readable, this will ensure you get the help you need more quickly. I added in some code from your comment below, next time simply update your question to include anything you forgot that could be relevant. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to relatively find the `span`.

```js
$(".calculate").click(function () {
  console.log($(this).children("span").html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number" id="number7"><br>
  <a href="" class="calculate"><span>7</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this with plain JavaScript, you could use the following script:

```
function calculate(event) {
  var value = parseInt(event.currentTarget.innerText, 10);
}
```

This will get the text of the element that you've bound with `onclick="calculate(event)"` and run it through the `parseInt` function. You can [read up more on parseInt on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), but essentially it converts strings to integers. Now you the integer value of `7` stored as the variable `value` and you can do what you wish with it.